# Downloading images from Amazon S3: Frontend or Backend

Tags: angular, laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Im doing an Angular-Laravel application (Laravel is serving as a REST API for my Angular app), and I am using Amazon S3 file storage system for uploading photos.

Right now I am downloading Amazon S3 files from my Laravel server and then it is being used by the Angular application, but speed is so low.

I have not tried to load Amazon S3 images directly from Angular because of safety reasons: I'm scared it could be hijacked and exploded.

My question is, am I using the best way for consuming S3 server? should I load them directly from my Angular application? Otherwise, is there any way of loading them faster from my Laravel API?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Amazon S3 exposes a JavaScript SDK that can be used to invoke Amazon S3 operations from a JS app. You can use this API to perform Amazon S3 operations from your Angular app. As long as you keep your creds safe, no need to worry about someone hacking your account.

If you are not familiar with using the AWS SDK for JavaScript to perform Amazon S3 operations, refer to the Developer Guide.

[What's the AWS SDK for JavaScript?](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v3/developer-guide/welcome.html)

Comment: Thank you very much! :)

Answer (score 1):

You should let your backend (in this case Laravel app) generate a pre-signed URL and return it to the frontend. You can then use that URL in your frontend and make direct requests to S3.